# println overtypes first argument

Tags: java, println

Sorry about the basic question, I'm still very new to Java.

When I try to use `println` to print a `String` variable followed by a colon the colon overtypes the first letter of the `String` variable.

So for example I type the following command

```
System.out.println(planetName + ":");
```

...and get this as output (Lets say the planet name is Zeta Alpha II)

```
:eta Alpha II
```

What am I doing wrong? If I omit the colon then the variable prints normally. Everything else works fine, I have tried `printf` solutions and using a `char` variable to no avail also.

**ANSWER**: As JimGarrison was so kind to suggest in the comments, the input file had \r characters (i.e. it was in CRLF DOS \r\n format.), a quick run of `dos2unix` fixed the input data and solved the problem

Comment: Seems to be more of an issue with the console/terminal you're using than with Java itself.

Comment: I think `planetName` has `"Zeta Alpha II\r"`.

Comment: It is extremely likely that the string you are printing contains a carriage-return character (`0x0D`) at the end.  How was the `tm` map populated?

Comment: Where is the '\r' coming from?

Comment: Again... HOW DID THE `tm` MAP GET POPULATED?  The `\r` was probably in the input data.

Comment: @JimGarrison I read your comment before it was edited, sorry. I added the first half of the code. The source data file was a mass of unsorted (name, planet) entries.

Comment: OK, now go examine the input file with a hex editor to see if you can find a `\r` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @JimGarrison I checked the file format using 'file' and it turns out the input data was DOS (i.e. CRLF) format. A quick run of dos2unix fixed this right up. Answer added, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file is in DOS format with each line ending with `\r\n`.

Remove the `\r` with a Dos-to-Unix utility such as `dos2unix`